# Rasa entities are not readable in custom message

Tags: slack, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

am building a conversational chatbot for slack using rasa, and everything is working fine, so i decided to add some interactive messages with custom message and buttons, but the entities are not readable in custom message.

**Rasa version:** 1.3.7

**Python version:** 3.7

**Issue:** i want to output the entities that the user has chosen using the custom key.

it works very well with the text key using the code below in yaml:

```
utter_submit_leave_authorization:
  - text: "your request is under review following the parameters:\n
    - certificate: {certif_type}\n
    - Departure date: {dep_date}\n
    - Half day: {dep_date_half_day}\n
    - End date: {end_date}\n
    - Half day: {end_date_half_day}"
```

and the output is like:

[image]

but in case of using the custom key with the code below :

```
- custom:
    blocks:
    - type: section
      text:
        type: mrkdwn
        text: 'your request is under review following the parameters :'
    - type: section
      fields:
      - type: mrkdwn
        text: "*Departure date:*\n{dep_date}"
      - type: mrkdwn
        text: "*Half day:*\n{dep_date_half_day}"
      - type: mrkdwn
        text: "*End date:*\n{end_date}"
      - type: mrkdwn
        text: "*Half day:*\n{end_date_half_day}"
      - type: mrkdwn
        text: "*Type:*\n{certif_type}"
```

and the output is like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one of the Rasa maintainers.
Thanks for your detailed issue description. That helped me a lot in finding the issue!
Interpolating entities in lists in custom messages wasn't supported so far. I created a pull request and will merge and release this asap. Please follow the PR for updates on this: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/pull/4835

Cheers,
Tobi

Comment: Thank you very much, when this will be released?

Comment: It was released with Rasa 1.5.1!